# Connect Azure function app to Mq using ssl

Tags: c#, .net-6.0, ibm-mq, .net-framework-version

Has anyone connected to mq server from an Azure function app using Ssl? I'm getting different errors when trying to connect, it looks like the nuget or libraries are not enough and the client is needed which makes not posible to connect, but wanted to confirm if anyone has done, and if so, can you share how this can be active.

I try to connect from Azure function app to an Mq server, the function app uses .net6, I even use framework 4.8, try using ibm nuget package and only the dlls but didn't work

Comment: Can you update your question with the code snippet that you are using? Also let us know the errors you are getting

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Hi, the code is the same that appears in other questions I'm more interested in known if this is posible as function apps are serverles and the access to mq is restricted to domain accounts only